# How to make C++'s service call method wait for server's response?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, call-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to call three consecutive service call from c++ node like this

```
ros::ServiceClient srvcl1 = n.serviceClient<gazebo::Randomize>(
    "/randomize", false
);
ros::ServiceClient srvcl2 = n.serviceClient<amcl::Localization>(
    "/localization", false
);
ros::ServiceClient srvcl3 = n.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>(
    "/check", false
);

gazebo::Randomize srv1;
amcl::Localization srv2;
std_srvs::Empty srv3;

while(ros::ok()){
    if(srvcl1.call(srv1)){
        if(srvcl2.call(srv2)){
            if(srvcl3.call(srv3)){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the service server sometime takes long time to process client's request but in C++, `srvcl.call(srv)` method always done instantaneously regardless server progress. In order to make  current service call perform correctly, it must wait for server that serve previous service call to finish. I try to avoid using wait function that require time constant like `ros::Duration(0.5).sleep()`. This problem doesn't occur when using bash script such as

```
rosservice call /randomize;
rosservice call /localization;
rosservice call /check;
```

Does python have same problem? My last resort is using actionlib.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323885/how-to-make-c++%27s-service-call-method-wait-for-server%27s-response?/) by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-05-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-05-23**:
It would help to know what the implementations of those services are.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Services in `roscpp` are blocking by default. What you are trying to do should be working if the service implementations are taking time before they return. Check if your service implementations are not returning early for some reason.

However, I think that if you will *always* call these three services together in this order, then using an action is a more appropriate semantic construct.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a suspicion that may be the service clients are returning prematurely (check http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/service__client_8h_source.html#l00081) because the service calls are issued before the services are actually up and ready. So adding

```
srvcl1.waitForExistence();
srvcl2.waitForExistence();
srvcl3.waitForExistence();
```

before the loop should solve this issue.

(I am assuming the service servers are working fine since the rosservice call commands are working fine. It would always help to post a more descriptive code than just snippets to provide a more authoritative answer :))

---

Originally posted by [Namal Senarathne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3870/namal-senarathne/) with karma: 246 on 2019-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3